Preview coil remote image with jetpack compose
I have a very simple component:
@Composable
fun LoadableImage(
    url: String?,
    cornerRadius: Dp = 10.dp,
    description: String? = ""
) {
    SubcomposeAsyncImage(
        model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
            .data(url)
            .crossfade(true)
            .build(),
        loading = {
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        },
        contentDescription = description,
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        modifier = Modifier.clip(RoundedCornerShape(cornerRadius))
    )
    /*
    AsyncImage(
        model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
            .data(url)
            .crossfade(true)
            .build(),
        placeholder = painterResource(id = R.drawable.mock_game_card),
        contentDescription = "",
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        modifier = Modifier
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .background(Color.Red)
    )
     */
}

Tried AsyncImage with a placerholder and SubcomposeAsyncImage (ideally I prefer the second in order to add the loading indicator). As I suspected, the image doesn't show up in the preview, but I'm wondering if this is even possible or at least I could somehow pass a local url in the preview.
What's the right approach to see coil images in the previews?
EDIT
It seems that AsyncImage with a placeholder is actually working, but still I would like to achieve the same with SubcomposeAsyncImage, which doesn't have a placeholder attribute.
Here's my preview code.-
@Preview(
    showBackground = true
)
@Composable
fun PreviewLoadableImage() {
    MyTheme {
        LoadableImage(
            url = Game.defaultGame.thumbnail
        )
    }
}


What do you mean by preview? As far as I know Coil has no preview feature. Or do you mean a Compose @Preview? Then your question would greatly benefit from having that as code as well.

Thank you @Leviathan, I'm talking about a compose @Preview, my test is pretty straight forward, but will add it to the question.

Then your question will basically be the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75525585/compose-preview-with-coil-image-from-url, won't it? Unfortunately that question doesn't have an answer...

Yep, I'm aware of that one and other similar questions, but in my case I'd be happy also if I can just use a mock local image.
